# Cout'ing array of length 20 outputs 23 characters

Tags: c++

When I cout an array of length 20, it couts 3 extra symbols at the end, any help?

```
char b[20];
for(int i=0; i<zmoniuSk; i++)
{
    in.read(b, 1); //dont mind this
    in.read(b, 20);
    zmogus[i].name = b;
    cout << b;
}
```

Should output this:

> Petras A. Petraitis

But instead it outputs this:

> Petras A. Petraitis øþi

Comment: Is the data nul-terminated in where you are reading it from? (hint - I am pretty sure it is not)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::string`? The documentation of [`std::basic_istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) has an example, of how one may use it with `std::string`, instead of `char` array.

Comment: Before the `cout`, do a `b[19] = '\0';`

Comment: Or, you can use `cout.write(b, 20)` so you don't need a null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your C-String is not correctly terminated with `'\0'` character.

```
char b[21] = {0};      // Make sure that you 
                       //   1. Have enough space for a terminating '\0'
                       //   2. You make sure that b[20] is an '\0' so that
                       //      your C string is correctly terminated.

for(int i=0; i<zmoniuSk; i++)
{
    in.read(b, 1); //dont mind this
    in.read(b, 20);
    zmogus[i].name = b;  // Assuming this is a std::string
    cout << b;           // This should now work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is overrunning the buffer of `b` when you try to print it out. The overload only knows that it's taking in an object of type `char*`, and when it receives such an object, it assumes that whatever string is being pointed to is null-terminated. But your code makes no effort to guarantee that it is null-terminated.

You should instead use one of these two methods:

```
char b[21];
b[20] = 0;
for(int i=0; i<zmoniuSk; i++)
{
    in.read(b, 1); //dont mind this
    in.read(b, 20);
    zmogus[i].name = b;
    cout << b;
}
```

Or

```
std::string b;
b.resize(20);
for(int i=0; i<zmoniuSk; i++)
{
    in.read(b.data(), 1); //dont mind this
    in.read(b.data(), 20);
    zmogus[i].name = b; //type of name might need to be changed...
    cout << b;
}
```

This is yet another reason to avoid C-style arrays, and prefer the C++ equivalent constructs.